# Autocomplete importing with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

How come I can't get rid of these red underlines? And that I can't autocomplete import in PyCharm?

datatype.py:

```
class DataType:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value
```

Here it is being used in `address.py`:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: The module is `datatypes`.  Outside of that, I'm not sure if you have it previously imported and exposed as `Datatype` in your `__init__.py` file, so I can't say that'll *work*, but the basic issue is that you were missing an "s".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

package name is `datatypes`, you use `from datatype import DataType`

It should be:

```
  # imports module datatype
  from datatypes import datatype as dt

  # uses class DataType
  dt.DataType
```

Update:

[image]

[image]

I added another package name `test` and module `datatype.py` under it.
and try all import possibilities, all of them can be imported.
[image]

Update:
You should check your `project interpreter` ,click `>>File >> Settings >> Project Interpreter`

Comment: @Liondancer  did you setup your project interpreter? I tested with python2.7 and 3.4 both work.

Comment: So originally this project was using python 3 as the interpreter. I think it was caused because someone built this project in sublime python2 and when I opened it in pycharm with python3 maybe there was some overhead missing. I changed the interpreter to python2 and it actually fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

```python
from .datatype import DataType
```